# Parcel live reload does not works for simple html

Tags: parceljs

I learning parcel js. In the documentation, there is described live reload.

> https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html

I suspect that when I will change the content of HTML file I will see that my website is reloading and a project will be rebuilt.

---

How to reproduce the bug?

I typed two bash scripts:

> prepare.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

HTML="<html><body>1</body></html>";

echo ${HTML} > index.html;
```

It creates the simplest possible HTML file.

1) Run this script `bash prepare.sh`.

2) Now in the second terminal run parcel.

```
parcel index.html --no-cache --no-hmr --log-level 5
```

Then create a script to do the main test:

> test.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

HTML="<html><body>1</body></html>";

echo ${HTML} > index.html;


# I checking if html served by parcel contains 1, it should and conatin
if [[ $(curl -s localhost:1234 | grep 1 | wc -l) -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "GREAT when the index is replaced project is rebuilt";
else
    echo "WRONG";
fi

# I replacing 1 inside of a body tag to 12 
perl -pi -e 's/1/12/g' index.html

echo "waiting 1 second for the rebuild...";
sleep 1;

# I checking if html served by parcel contains 2, it should but not conatin 
if [[ $(curl -s localhost:1234 | grep 2 | wc -l) -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "GREAT";
else
    echo "WRONG but when I only modified file project parcel did not see it";
fi
```

So. I creating HTML file again (replacing it) and I can see that building process is invoked. But when I only modifying file changing string inside of body tag, then nothing happens. Parcel server did not detect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The [`--no-hmr` flag](https://parceljs.org/cli.html#disable-hmr) disables [both HMR and *any* type of reloading](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1915).** For the simple HTML in your question, simply removing the `--no-hmr` flag should work.

However, unexpected side-effects may occur in more complex HTML that is modified via JS. There was a [pull request to add a `--reload` flag](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/pull/443), but it was never merged. You can try to modify your own parcel based on the PR, or try one of the forks that [implement](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/289#issuecomment-352154332) plain [reload](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/289#issuecomment-354550528).